# Sequelize.js setter methods dont work

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I have the following code in a sequelize.js test script:

```
department.hasMany(employee,{as:'employees', foreignKey:'DepartamentoID'});

let prog = department.build({nombre:'Programming Dept.'});
let admin = department.build ({ nombre:'Administration'});
let maintenance = department.build( {nombre:'Maintenance'});
prog.save();
admin.save();
maintenance.save();

//create employees
const pepe = employee.build ({ nombre:'Pepe Gonzalez', posicion:'Manager'});
pepe.save();
const irma = employee.build ({ nombre:'Irma Pérez', posicion:'Office Hurricane'});
irma.save();
const ima = employee.build ({ nombre:'Ima Programmer', posicion:'Dev'});
ima.save();
prog.setEmployees([pepe,irma,ima]);
prog.save();

const juanito = employee.build ({ nombre:'Juanito Velez', posicion:'Manager'});
juanito.save();
const zoyla = employee.build ({ nombre:'Zoyla Gartija', posicion:'Dev'});
zoyla.save();
const gallu = employee.build ({ nombre:'Gallu el jíbaro', posicion:'Musician'});
gallu.save();
admin.setEmployees([juanito,zoyla,gallu]);
admin.save();
```

The code runs successfully, and all records are created in the target database, however, the Employees table has its 'DepartamentoID' column blank on all records.  According to the docs, when I create a hasMany relationship, a setter method is automatically created. Am I doing something wrong or just misreading the docs?

Answer (score 0):

You will need to explicitly set `DepartamentoID`. For instance:

```
let maintenance = department.build( {nombre:'Maintenance'});
maintenance.save();

//create employees
const pepe = employee.build ({
  nombre:'Pepe Gonzalez',
  posicion:'Manager',
  DepartamentoID: maintenance.id
});
pepe.save();
```

Comment: But according to http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/associations.html#associating-objects, I do not need to do this. Setter methods, apparently, should be able to set the foreign key by themselves. Perhaps I need to call .sync()?